# How to add the values of 2 cells in a forEach loop in an ejs file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have a table in an ejs file that loop through a collection(schema) and populate the information. i want to add the values of 2 cells(subQamount and subClaimsum) in that table and show it in another cell(the last one). Apparently i cant use a javascript function and get the element by id (it only get the element of first run). Is there any other way I can do this math?

Here is the table:

```
<% tracker.subcontractors.forEach(function(data){ %>    

        <tr>

            <td class="button"><%= data.subName %></td>
            <td class="button"><%= data.subContact %></td>
            <td class="button"><%= data.subQno %></td>
            <td class="button">$ <%= commaNumber(data.subQamount) %></td> 
            <td class="button">$ <%= commaNumber(data.subClaimsum) %></td> 
            <td class="button"><a href="/tracker/<%= tracker._id %>/subcontractor/<%= data._id %>/subclaim"><button style="font-size:13px; padding: 2px; margin-left: 20px;" class="btn btn-info">open</button></a></td>
            <td class="button">$ </td>

        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add these 2 :

```
<%= commaNumber(data.subQamount) +  commaNumber(data.subClaimsum) %>
```